# Axis values as a product with 10 including multiplication symbol in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart were I compare 2 values  of large numbers with error bars between each other. It is required to use a specific scientific notation, presenting values like 53000000 as 5.3 × 10^7. For this task, I previously used successfully the following commands:

```
value <-c(24000000, 30000000)
Station <-c("A", "B")
SD <-c(15000000, 17000000)

datatest2 <- data.frame(Station,value, SD)

scientific <- function(x){
  ifelse(x==0, "0", parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("e", "%*% 10^", scientific_format()(x)))))
}
tt<-ggplot(datatest2, aes(y=value, x=Station)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity", fill = c("A"="khaki1", "B"="khaki4")) +
  geom_text(label = c("a", "a"), aes(y = c(50000000, 50000000), x = c(1, 2)), size = 6) +
  ylab(expression(paste("Value", sep=""))) +
  xlab(expression(paste("Sampling station", sep=""))) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = ggplot2::guide_axis(n.dodge = 1), labels = function(x) stringr::str_wrap(x, width = 15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Station, ymin=value-SD, ymax=value+SD),position=position_dodge(width=0.9), alpha=0.9, width=0.4, colour="black", size=1) +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,53000000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), label = scientific) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=18, colour = 'black'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18, colour = "black"), axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1), axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1), axis.ticks.length=unit(.25, "cm"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=20), colour = 'black'),axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(r=25)),
        legend.justification=c(1.5,0.5), legend.position="bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="white", size=18, linetype="dotted"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=18, margin=margin(r=55)),
        legend.title=element_text(colour = "white", size = 0))

tt
```

Due to some other reasons, I am forced to use R version 4.2.2, resulting in the provision of empty squares at the location were the multiplication symbol should be.
How do I have to adjust my script to get my values in the format of 5.3 × 10^7 WITHOUT changing my R version

Comment: Works for me in R 4.2.0 (don't have 4.2.2 handy but I doubt there's a difference).  I suspect this has more to do with encodings/fonts available on your system than on R version ... can you provide relevant bits of `sessionInfo()` (i.e. OS, locale, etc.) ?  It would also help if you can (1) add relevant `library()` calls (`library("scales"); library("ggplot2")` so your code is self-sufficient; (2) reduce the example to a **minimal** example (i.e. just `ggplot(...) + geom_bar(...) + scale_y_continuous(...)`, with none of the other geoms/scales/labels, would probably illustrate the issue)

Comment: To test whether this is font-related, you could try `axis.text = element_text(size = 18, family = 'serif', color = 'black')`.  You may simply be missing the multiplication symbol from your default font.